# Difference between "camel-activemq" vs "activemq-camel"

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We are upgrading our system to newest stable frameworks/libraries. However, i found difficulty in understand between these two `camel-activemq` vs `activemq-camel`. Below are details:

1. We are upgrading `ActiveMQ to 5.16.2` version. Here AMQ provides `"activemq-camel"` libraries with its own camel dependencies like:
   [image]
2. Also, we are planning to migrate a service which runs on `camel-2.x` to `3.11.3`. Here  i see camel provides `camel-activemq` with version `3.11.3`. So i'm confused what to choose here. Will there be incompatibility if i choose `camel-activmeq-3.11.3` while routing messages to `AMQ-5.16.2`.

When i opened both jars, i see packages/classes different in both jars.
[image]
[image]

Maven repo says both are **"AciveMQ component for Camel"**

Can anyone please clarify difference between these two `activemq-camel` and `camel-activemq`
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `camel-activemq` or even just `camel-jms` with an `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. The `activemq-camel` module in the ActiveMQ project is [going to be removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8033).

Comment: Second part of this question (not in the title, I know) was whether you can use camel 3.x versions in an activemq 5.x. I miss that part in the answer (and cannot find another question about that part and the part that is answered was already clear to us)

Comment: @Kukeltje, you should ask this as a new question.